# Replacing indexes on each element and its content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to replace a text recurring multiple times in several elements with the same id, both in the its tag and its inner html, with a progressive number. Example:

```
<div id="element_x_">
 <p>Line number _x_</p>
</div>
<div id="element_x_">
 <p>Line number _x_</p>
</div>
```

Should become:

```
<div id="element1">
 <p>Line number 1</p>
</div>
<div id="element2">
 <p>Line number 2</p>
</div>
```

What I tried so far is this:

```
$('#element_x_').each(function(i) {
 $(this).contents($(this).contents.replace(/_x_/g, i));
});
```

But that's just not working, I guess the .contents function is not what I need and I'm not sure how to select the entire element (tag + content) of each iteration for the replace to do its job.

Comment: But what renders this invalid HTML markup??? Canoot you change it before rendering it?

Comment: markup is initially invalid: identifiers must be unique

Comment: It's a dynamic collection of fieldsets coming from Zend Framework 2, I use  a similar method to create the elements when rendering the form (ZF2 gives a template to copy, containing such indexes, and I replace them with JS), but if I submit the form and it's invalid, I get the same number of fields returned, but without the indexes replaced, since they weren't created by my JS but by the framework itself.

Comment: With attribute selector you can: https://jsfiddle.net/01L8xvnp/ But you shouldn't, as many people said here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you're starting with an **invalid document**, since `id` values must be unique. So you have no guarantee that the browser will retain the invalid `id` after parsing. In practice, I've never met one that didn't, but I'd still remove those duplicate `id`s and give the relevant elements a shared `class` instead.

If you do that, then

```
$(".the-class").each(function(i) {
    this.id = "element" +i;
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/_x_/g, i);
});
```

```js
$(".the-class").each(function(i) {
  this.id = "element" + i;
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/_x_/g, i);
});
```

```html
<div class="the-class">
  <p>Line number _x_</p>
</div>
<div class="the-class">
  <p>Line number _x_</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't do that, you could use an attribute selector:

```
$("[id=element_x_]").each(function(i) {
    this.id = "element" +i;
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/_x_/g, i);
});
```

```js
$("[id=element_x_]").each(function(i) {
  this.id = "element" + i;
  this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/_x_/g, i);
});
```

```html
<div id="element_x_">
  <p>Line number _x_</p>
</div>
<div id="element_x_">
  <p>Line number _x_</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Which works with the current jQuery and major browsers. But I wouldn't.

Note that in both cases, we're assuming you want **all** `_x_` inside these elements to be replaced with the same `i` value.

---

A note about `this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace(/_x_/g, i);`: While quick and easy, it will also tear down all of the elements inside the element you do it on, throwing away any event handlers on them, and then make the browser recreate them by parsing the new HTML. It will also look for `_x_` **everywhere**, not just in the text. That may be what you want, of course.

Having done `this.id = ...` to update the `id`, if you **only** want to process the text and not tear down recreate elements, jQuery actually makes that fairly easy with its `contents` function, but we need to recurse:

```
$(".the-class").each(function(i) {
  this.id = "element" + i;
  updateElement(this, /_x_/g, i);
});
function updateElement(element, rex, rep) {
  $(element).contents().each(function() {
    switch (this.nodeType) {
        case 1: // Element
            updateElement(this, rex, rep);
            break;
        case 3: // Text node
            this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(rex, rep);
            break;
    }
  });
}
```

```js
$(".the-class").each(function(i) {
  this.id = "element" + i;
  updateElement(this, /_x_/g, i);
});
function updateElement(element, rex, rep) {
  $(element).contents().each(function() {
    switch (this.nodeType) {
        case 1: // Element
            updateElement(this, rex, rep);
            break;
        case 3: // Text node
            this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(rex, rep);
            break;
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="the-class">
  <p>Line number _x_</p>
</div>
<div class="the-class">
  <p>Line number _x_ <span>Nested _x_</span></p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the current element with the replaced content. But note that this is not a good design - because ID of an element must be unique and any event handlers/data attached to those elements will be lost by doing replacement

```js
$('div[id="element_x_"]').each(function(i) {
  $(this).replaceWith(this.outerHTML.replace(/_x_/g, i + 1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element_x_">
  <p>Line number _x_</p>
</div>
<div id="element_x_">
  <p>Line number _x_</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not loop over and `ID` as it is supposed to be unique. You need to add a `class`, or select your elements by type (`div`)

```js
$('.elt_x').each(function(i) {
  var thisElt = $(this);
  var thisChild = thisElt.children("p");
  thisElt.attr("id", thisElt.attr("id").replace("_x_", i+1)).removeClass("elt_x");
  thisChild.text(thisChild.text().replace("_x_", i+1));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element_x_" class="elt_x">
  <p>Line number _x_</p>
</div>
<div id="element_x_" class="elt_x">
  <p>Line number _x_</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change from id to class id must be unique your can do it by class.

```
    <div class="element_x_">
     <p>Line number _x_</p>
    </div>
    <div class="element_x_">
     <p>Line number _x_</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.element_x_').each(function(i) {
     $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/_x_/g, i+1));
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

On other way, handling attribute id and `p` text:

```
$('[id=element_x_]').attr('id', function(index) {
  var i = ++index;
  $(this).children('p').text(function(_, txt){
      return txt.replace('_x_', i)
  })
  return "element" + i;
});
```

That's said, having to doing it client side seems really wrong. This should be handled server side, before rendering the HTML markup.